# How to handle ISO date strings in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm brand new to typescript, so I'm trying to get the hang of it.

A network request is going to return a JSON object with a field in ISO Date string format.

```
data : Data = {when: "2016-07-13T18:46:01.933Z"}
```

When I create the type signature for this interface, is there any way of specifying that this is actually an ISO timestamp or do I just have to use string?

```
interface Data {
  when: string
}
```

I found out I could use a type alias which mentally helps, but doesn't really validate the ISO string.

```
type iso = string
interface Data {
  when: iso
}
```

On a similar vein, I'm curious if there's anyway to generate js validation from these typescript annotations so I can validate the information received by the endpoint, otherwise the rest of my typed application is worthless.

If this is possible then it would be really cool if this iso string could be coerced into an actual Date object.

As I said, I'm new to typescript, so I'm not sure if this is beyond the scope of what typescript is supposed to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it would be really cool if this iso string could be coerced into an actual Date object

No this is not possible. For javascript there's nothing to do with typescript's interfaces. (JS is not generated at all for interfaces). Also all the type checks are done at "compile" or "transpile" time, not at run time.

What you **can** do, is to use [`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function when parsing json. For example:

```
const datePattern = /\d{4}-[01]\d-[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d\.\d+([+-][0-2]\d:[0-5]\d|Z)/;
const json = '{"when": "2016-07-13T18:46:01.933Z"}';

const result = JSON.parse(json, (key: any, value: any) => {
    const isDate = typeof value === 'string' && datePattern.exec(value);
    return isDate? new Date(value) : value;
});
```

Also you can identify `Date` property by key and in case it doesn't match the date pattern you could throw an error or do whatever you want.

Comment: Youn could potentially use Zod for this

Answer (score 11):

You can use a [Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

```
import moment from 'moment'

export const isISO = (input: any): input is tISO =>
  moment(input, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid()
```

Then you can use whatever custom logic in your you want to handle any bad dates, e.g.:

```
const maybeISO = fetch('Maybe ISO')

if (isISO(maybeISO)) {
  // proceed
} else {
  // check other format?
  // log error?
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Hint: you do not have to rely on a 3rd party library, because the built-in `Date` can parse ISO-8601 strings as well.

Answer (score 10):

### Try this:

```
// In TS, interfaces are "open" and can be extended
interface Date {
  /**
   * Give a more precise return type to the method `toISOString()`:
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString
   */
  toISOString(): TDateISO;
}

type TYear         = `${number}${number}${number}${number}`;
type TMonth        = `${number}${number}`;
type TDay          = `${number}${number}`;
type THours        = `${number}${number}`;
type TMinutes      = `${number}${number}`;
type TSeconds      = `${number}${number}`;
type TMilliseconds = `${number}${number}${number}`;

/**
 * Represent a string like `2021-01-08`
 */
type TDateISODate = `${TYear}-${TMonth}-${TDay}`;

/**
 * Represent a string like `14:42:34.678`
 */
type TDateISOTime = `${THours}:${TMinutes}:${TSeconds}.${TMilliseconds}`;

/**
 * Represent a string like `2021-01-08T14:42:34.678Z` (format: ISO 8601).
 *
 * It is not possible to type more precisely (list every possible values for months, hours etc) as
 * it would result in a warning from TypeScript:
 *   "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent. ts(2590)
 */
type TDateISO = `${TDateISODate}T${TDateISOTime}Z`;
```

The [source](https://gist.github.com/MrChocolatine/367fb2a35d02f6175cc8ccb3d3a20054)

Comment: A link to official docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Comment: This answer is misleading, since `${number}` isn't limited to an integer digit, as one might assume from reading this answer. Scientific notation and decimals are assignable to `${number}`, and this code compiles: `const date: TDateISODate = '2000.3e+3-3.223232e2-123456789.12321312e12'` Also, template literals only apply at compile time, user input will not be guarded at all. You cannot avoid runtime checks to validate a date string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DateFromISOString` from [io-ts-types](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts-types/docs/modules)
See its [documentation](https://gcanti.github.io/io-ts-types/modules/DateFromISOString.ts.html).

Comment: thanks for the hint, @RasmusGP. I have just updated the links after the author moved the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Closes enough for my use case:

```
export type DateIso = `${YFirst}${Digit}${Digit}-${MM}-${DD}`;

type YFirst = '19' | '20'; // change this if you accept dates outside of 19xx & 20xx years
type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9';
type MM = '01' | '02' | '03' | '04' | '05' | '06' | '07' | '08' | '09' | '10' | '11' | '12'
type DD = '01' | '02' | '03' | '04' | '05' | '06' | '07' | '08' | '09' | '10' | '11' | '12' | '13' | '14' | '15' | '16' | '17' | '18' | '19' | '20' | '21' | '22' | '23' | '24' | '25' | '26' | '27' | '28' | '29' | '30' | '31';
```