# Typescript convert all date from interface to string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to transform all the `Date` types definition from my interface to `string`, as it get automatically transformed to `string` on JSON stringify.

```
interface Item {
   key: string;
   value: number;
   created: Date;
}

const item: Item = { key: 'abc', value: 1, created: Date() };

// convert to JSON
const itemJson = JSON.stringify(item);

// convert back itemJson to an object
const item2 = JSON.parse(itemJson);

// item2 is not of type `Item` as JSON.stringify convert Dates to strings
// so item2 is of type: { key: string; value: number; created: string; }
```

Would there be a kind of feature to transform the `Date` type from my interface to `string`? Something like `const item2: ToJSON<Item> = JSON.parse(itemJson);`

**Note:**
I don't want to transform back `item2.created` to Date but I want to create a new `interface` corresponding to the conversion `item` to `item2`. So `item` is different of `item2` and should stay different, therefor I need a new interface for `item2`. Of course, I could do it manually, but I have a bunch of interface to convert, I would like to do this with something similar to a utility type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

**Note2:**
The goal is to get a new interface called `Item2`

```
interface Item2 {
   key: string;
   value: number;
   created: string;
}
```

Something like `type Item2 = ToJSON<Item>`.

Comment: why not use type coersion ```const item2 = JSON.parse(itemJson) as Item```...the ```JSON.parse()``` function returns type ```any``` so you can coerce it

Comment: Because `JSON.parse(itemJson) as Item` is wrong as `created` is now a string.

Comment: Would you be ok with changing your interface to a class, then defining a static method to parse type ```any``` to type ```Item```?

Comment: Hold on I actually found something interesting, apparently, the ```JSON.parse``` function takes a second callback argument called a reviver function..check it out one sec

Comment: Actually on my project most of them are class and not interface, I just used interface here cause it was easier to represent. Can you elaborate on your idea?

Comment: Yes `JSON.parse` get a second parameter but I don't want to convert the string back to date. I want to keep them as string...

Comment: Yes the first line is fine, I want to convert my type definition from `{ key: string; value: number; created: Date; }` to `{ key: string; value: number; created: string; }`.

Comment: ok check my edit in the answer down there, its a suggestion though coz interfaces don't get to JS

Comment: You should have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html to understand.

Comment: Dude i understand now...you're looking for a utility definition that will basically acknowledge your interface coming from the JSON.parse state...```ToJSON<Item>```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

TypeScript type system FTW:

```
interface Item {
  key: string;
  value: number;
  created: Date;
}

type SwapDatesWithStrings<T> = {
  [k in keyof(T)]: (T[k] extends Date ? string : T[k]);
}

type JsonItems = SwapDatesWithStrings<Item>;

// JsonItems is the same as:
// interface JsonItems {
//   key: string;
//   value: number;
//   created: string;
// }
```

It works deriving a generic type `SwapDatesWithStrings` from the base type `T`, with the same set of properties of `T`, but with a twist on the property type: properties deriving from Date are converted to strings.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is this recursive?

Comment: No, it's not, but it could probably be made recursive exchanging the last T[k] with SwapDatesWithStrings<T[k]>.

Answer (score 5):

Extending on @alberto-chiesa's answer, we can make it convert dates which are in a nested section of the object and also allow for optional values too:

```
export interface Item {
    myDate: Date;
    dateRange: {
        start?: Date;
        end: Date;
    };
}

type NestedSwapDatesWithStrings<T> = {
    [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends Date | undefined
        ? string
        : T[k] extends object
        ? NestedSwapDatesWithStrings<T[k]>
        : T[k];
};

type ItemWithStringDates = NestedSwapDatesWithStrings<Item>;

// Result:
// {
//    myDate: string;
//    dateRange: {
//        start: string | undefined;
//        end: string;
//    };
// }
```

It essentially recursively tries to convert `Dates` to `strings`

Comment: Recursive types! Truly do love to see it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, 2 types are needed, that apart from the type annotation of a single field are otherwise identical.

### Solution: Generic interface

Making the interface generic would allow you to parametrise it with type arguments, and re-use it across both of your types. See [TypeScript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for more.

Applying this on your example:

```js
interface Item<T> {
    key: string;
    value: number;
    created: T;
}

const item: Item<Date> = { key: 'abc', value: 1, created: Date() };

// convert to JSON
const itemJson = JSON.stringify(item);

// convert back itemJson to an object
const item2: Item<string> = JSON.parse(itemJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider declaring  `Item` as a class.
There are many libraries that help transforming plain object into class instances like e.g. [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)

Answer (score 0):

Ok check this out its awesome, i got it from this dudes post [How to handle ISO date strings in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359563/how-to-handle-iso-date-strings-in-typescript)

So he's like you can add a revived function so lets apply it to your problem here:

```
interface Item {
   key: string;
   value: number;
   created: Date | string;
}

const item: Item = { key: 'abc', value: 1, created: Date() };

// convert to JSON
const itemJson = JSON.stringify(item);

// convert back itemJson to an object
// The juice is here, what you do is add the function as a second argument
const item2 = JSON.parse(itemJson, (key: any, value: any) => {
    // and in here you do your extra stuff...

    return Date.parse(value) ? new Date(value): value;

});
```

#Edit: To note, interfaces don't make it to JS, they get removed so if you want to acknowledge your interface potentially having a string type, then maybe define your interface like so:

```
interface Item {
   key: string;
   value: number;
   created: Date | string; // at least this way you are acknowledging a potential string type
}
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I don't want to convert back the `created` string back to date, I want to update my type definition.

Comment: Ayt i made an edit considering your interface definition

Comment: In my case `Item` cannot have `created: Date | string;` it should be `created: Date;` only!

Answer (score 0):

While @Dolan's answer satisfies original question, it could be tuned up a little bit for more complex cases to deal with `undefined` not only in "leaf" types, but when some sub-path is optional:

```
export type WithDatesStringified<T> = T extends Date
  ? string
  : T extends object
  ? { [k in keyof T]: WithDatesStringified<T[k]> }
  : T;
```

It's basically all the same type, just turned inside out, so it can work both with (`DatesStringifiedToIsoString<Date>`) and with more complex cases like this:

```
const value: { optionalPath?: { date: string } } =
  {} as WithDatesStringified<{ optionalPath?: { date: Date } }>;
```