# Convert object number fields to string

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a function, which takes an object as a parameter, it should process all fields of the object and convert all number fields to string. I would like TypeScript to know which fields the resulting object has and its types. I would also like it to handle nested structures.

Here is the *not* type-safe function:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

export const numbersToString = <T extends object>(obj: T) => {
  obj = _.cloneDeep(obj)

  _.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (_.isNumber(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = String(obj[key])
    } else if (_.isArray(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = obj[key].map((el) => (_.isObject(el) ? numbersToString(el) : el))
    } else if (_.isObject(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = numbersToString(obj[key])
    }
  })

  return obj
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65421207

In case someone wonders, this would be the solution for the question above:

```
import _ from 'lodash'

type SwapNumberWithStrings<T> = {
  [k in keyof T]: T[k] extends number ? string : T[k] extends object ? SwapNumberWithStrings<T[k]> : T[k]
}

export const numbersToString = <T extends object>(obj: T): SwapNumberWithStrings<T> => {
  obj = _.cloneDeep(obj)

  _.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (_.isNumber(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = String(obj[key])
    } else if (_.isArray(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = obj[key].map((el) => (_.isObject(el) ? numbersToString(el) : el))
    } else if (_.isObject(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = numbersToString(obj[key])
    }
  })

  return obj
}
```

Comment: To mark a duplicate, please use proper close reason rather than linking to the other answer.